# How to get a tight border around some spans in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML in bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="border rounded p-1" >
   <span style="background-color:red">m0: [0.17, 0.81]</span> 
   <span style="background-color:yellow">m1: [0.72, 0.80]</span> 
   <span style="background-color:lime">m2: [0.17, 0.21]</span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

It renders with a lot of extra space on the right end. How can I make the border enclose the spans tightly?

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/darkstarsys/aq9Laaew/255041/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surrounding div is a block element, so it will take up the full width. To solve this you can change this element to be an inline-block. I've done so by giving the div an id of wrap and assigned it the inline-block attribute in css:

```css
#wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div id="wrap" class="border rounded p-1"><span style="background-color:red">m0: [0.17, 0.81]</span> <span style="background-color:yellow">m1: [0.72, 0.80]</span> <span style="background-color:lime">m2: [0.17, 0.21]</span> </div>
</div>
```